# SUM of MAX(TOP x)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Say I have a table like the following:

```
PK Code Value
1  A    200
2  A    300
3  A    25
4  A    75
5  A    50
6  A    15
7  A    300
8  A    75
```

How would I get the value of the top 4 highest values where code=A (i.e. just want the sum of 300 + 300 + 200 + 75)

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

You can use a derived table or Common Table Expression to get the top 4 then `SUM` that.

```
SELECT SUM(Value) As Top4Sum
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP (4) Value
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE Code = 'A'
    ORDER BY Value DESC
) T
```

If you wanted the `SUM` of the `TOP 4` for every `Code` you could do

```
;WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY Value DESC) RN
         FROM   YourTable)
SELECT Code,
       SUM(Value)
FROM   CTE
WHERE  RN <= 4
GROUP  BY Code
```

Comment: Probably miss wrote the question, I want the sum of the 4 highest values where Code=A, I think putting Top 4 was a mistake - Sorry!!